# Circular hash collision where digest is pre-image: Could hash(a) = b, hash(b)=c, then hash(c)=a?

Tags: hash, sha-256, xor

For any SHA-family of algorithms (including Keccak) except for SHA1, would it be theoretically possible for there to **exist** a pre-image `a` whose hash digest `b` is the pre-image to the hash digest `c` which is the pre-image to `a` thus completing a circle (i.e. circular hash or collision of pre-image `a` with the digest `a`)?

${{hash(A)\to B}}$, ${{hash(B)\to C}}$ , ${{hash(C)\to A}}$

Given the use of XOR and bit-rotations, as well as padding and pre-processing and the many steps involved in hash functions such as SHA256 or SHA512, **would it be possible for the above circular hash scenario to exist?** (*despite the unlikelihood of it being found*)

P.S. candidate values include an all-zero string for pre-image or digest, or any valid-length output (i.e. 256, 512).

Comment: This is a generalization of [Does preimage resistance and/or collision resistance imply the infeasiblility of finding fixed points in hash functions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55802) See also [If you hashed a hash an infinite number of times would you end up with a unique hash?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25243)

Comment: A quick simulation indicates that a random function has an approximately 0.283 probability of having a cycle of length precisely 3...

Comment: @Gilles thanks for those related references, I hadn't seen them. Not sure if this answer would be applicable to SHA in terms of the Rho structure mentioned: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10661/213344

Comment: @poncho does that would mean there could be many such collisions at length 3?

Comment: @StevenHatzakis: potentially, yes.  However, it would seem to me that the probability of there being a large number of such cycles would likely be small...

Comment: @poncho: For $k=3$, $1-e^{-\frac1k} ≈ 0.283468689$. I haven't quite managed to come up with a 100% rigorous proof that that's the large-domain limit (except for $k=1$, which is the easy case), but I'm willing to bet that it is.

Comment: I've deleted my answer which was on the number of such collisions and asked it as a separate question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/how-many-hash-collision-will-exist-where-the-digest-is-a-pre-image/72524#72524  with a tentative answer.

Comment: The 28% holds for any sufficiently large space. If we remove the first size 3 cycle we will have the same 28% chance for having a second one. remove it and still 28%. So having at least k such cycles has probability  $0.28^k$ which drops rapidly with k.

Answer (score 4):

We like to think of hash functions as random functions, and there is no reason a random function shouldn't have a cycle of size 3 which is what you describe.
Obviously it would be very difficult to find such a cycle, we can discuss how likely is it a random function over space size $n$ has a cycle of size 3.

Ignoring cycles of size 1 and 2 which acount for a small portion of the space we have $n/3$ independent size 3 prefixes. each of these has probability $1/n$ to close a size 3 cycle. the chance they all miss is $(1-1/n)^{(n/3)}$ which is $(1/e)^{(1/3)}$ or 0.71653131057.
so the chance of at least 1 such cycle is 28% which is consistent with simulation results in comments above by poncho.

Comment: My hand wavy answer was wrong, this is a better one