# How many hash collision will exist where the digest is a pre-image?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

This question follows on from the question [Circular hash collision where digest is pre-image: Could hash(a) = b, hash(b)=c, then hash(c)=a?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72496/circular-hash-collision-where-digest-is-pre-image-could-hasha-b-hashb-c)

The question was answered but the issue of the number of collisions was also raised. I have moved my answer to this query as a separate question. The other question begins:

*For any SHA-family of algorithms (including Keccak) except for SHA1, would it be theoretically possible for there to* **exist** *a pre-image* `a` *whose hash digest* `b` *is the pre-image to the hash digest* `c` *which is the pre-image to* `a` *thus completing a circle (i.e. circular hash or collision of pre-image* `a` *with the digest* `a`)?

${{hash(A)\to B}}$, ${{hash(B)\to C}}$ , ${{hash(C)\to A}}$

The answer to this is yes. My question is, how many such collisions would typically exist?

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of 3-cycles in a random function on a large domain is $1/3$. More generally, for a random function on a set of size $n$, the expected number of cycles of length $\ell$ is asymptotically equivalent to $1/\ell$ as $n \to \infty$.

This result, along with a general approach to the combinatorical properties of random functions, can be found in the paper [Random Mapping Statistics](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46885-4_34.pdf) by Flajolet and Odlyzko (likely, the result has been derived elsewhere using different methods too).

Let me sketch how this result is obtained. Recall that the functional graph of a mapping is a set of components, each of which consists of a cycle to which trees are connected.

Let $t(z)$ be the exponential generating function for the number of (rooted) trees. It can be shown that (this is known as Cayley's formula)

$$t(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^{n - 1}}{n!} z^n.$$

Since components are cycles of trees, the generating function for the number of components is

$$\log\left(\frac{1}{1-t(z)}\right).$$

Also, the generating function for the number of functional graphs would then be the exponential of the above. In order to count the number of cycles of length $\ell$, one can construct a bivariate generating function for the number of functional graphs in which the second variable "marks" $\ell$-cycles. That is, instead of the above generating function for the number of components, we define

$$\log\left(\frac{1}{1-t(z)}\right) + (u- 1)\frac{t(z)^\ell}{\ell}.$$

That is, the term (in the Taylor series in the variable $t(z)$) corresponding to cycles of length $\ell$ is multiplied by the marker variable $u$. The desired bivariate generating function at the level of the functional graph is then

$$\xi(z, u) = \exp\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{1-t(z)}\right) + (u- 1)\frac{t(z)^\ell}{\ell}\right).$$

One can see that the generating function for the sum of number of cycles of length $\ell$ over all functional graphs of fixed size can then be computed as

$$\Xi(z) = \frac{\partial\xi(z, u)}{\partial u}\Bigg|_{u = 1} = \frac{z^\ell}{\ell(1 - t(z))}.$$

It remains to determine the Maclaurin series coefficients of the above, at least for terms of very high order. This is possible by singularity analysis. We use the fact (by Proposition 1 in the paper of Flajolet and Odlyzko) that (as $z \to 1/e$)

$$1 - t(z) \sim \sqrt{2(1 - ez)}.$$

Hence,

$$\Xi(z) \sim \frac{z^\ell}{\ell\sqrt{2(1 - ez)}}.$$

The singularity analysis technique (Theorem 1 in Flajolet and Odlyzko) then shows that (with $\Xi_n / n!$ the coefficient of order $n$)

$$\Xi_n \overset{\star_1}{\sim} e^n\,\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2}\ell}\,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\Gamma(1/2)} \sim \frac{e^n n!}{\ell\sqrt{2\pi n}} \overset{\star_2}{\sim} \frac{n^n}{\ell},$$

where $\star_1$ is the actual singularity analysis and $\star_2$ follows from Stirling's approximation $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\, n^n/e^n$. In order to obtain the expected value of the number of $\ell$-cycles of a random function on a set of size $n$, it suffices to divide by the number of such functions ($n^n$): $\Xi_n \sim 1/\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

I want argue heuristically that many such $3-$cycles are unlikely. Consider a random function $f$ mapping $X:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to itself. @MeirMaor showed that at least one such cycle has significant probability.

Consider two iterations of $f$ and note that the image set $Y=f(f(X)):=h(x)$ will typically have size roughly 
$$(1-e^{-1})^2\cdot n:=c^{-1} \cdot n.$$ Thus, on average, the inverse image $S_y:=h^{-1}(y)$ of each $y \in Y$ has size $c\approx 2.5.$ The argument I make would need floor and ceiling functions but the essence stays the same.

**Edit:** *The problem is harder than I thought. Thus, one needs to be a bit more careful, since in general non-uniform distributions amplify the collision probabilities, and the distribution of balls in roughly $c^{-1}\cdot n$ bins after the second iteration won't in general be flat.*

*If there was a single iteration of $h$ the maximal load would be with high probability $\log n/\log \log n$. After the second iteration, the maximal load is at most $(\log n/\log \log n)^2$, with high probability. This upper bound could be tightened by a tiny factor, but this is insignificant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins_problem, and the reference to the paper by Raab.*

Fix $y\in Y$ and note that if $f$ maps a point $y\in Y$ to a point in $S_y$ a $3-$cycle containing $y$ is completed. This has relatively low probability $c/n$ of happening and *if it doesn't occur* it means that $y$ is mapped to some other $S_{y'},$ thus reducing the probability that $f(y')$ completes a cycle containing $y'$ to $(c-1)/(n-1).$ This is because the inverse images $$\{S_y: y \in Y\}$$ form a partition of $X,$ and a point not in $S_y$ is in some other $S_{y'}.$

We now first approximate what happens by first ignoring
the fact that $S_y$ are of varying size, approximate the number of $3-$cycles by a Binomial distribution $$\mathrm{Bin}(n/c,c/n)$$ which has expectation $1$ and a rapidly decaying tail. This distribution only represents where $h(h(h(x)))$ falls in $X.$

However, what we really need is to weigh this distribution linearly by the actual size of the set $S_y$ in case it is hit. To obtain our upper bound we use the maximal size $(\log n/\log \log n)^2,$ giving an upper bound $O((\log n/\log \log n)^2)$ since the binomial well approximated by a poisson distribution with rate $1,$ and thus the probability still decays exponentially fast.